# How to print car detail from dict

Tags: python-3.x

```
cars = {"Austin 7": 1922, "Lancia Lambda": 1922, "Bugatti Type 35": 1924, "Hanomag 2": 1925,
        "Ford Model A": 1927, "Cadillac V16": 1930}

for i in range:
    

print("car: {}, year: {}".format(_, cars[_]))
```

Comment: Can someone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: You can list of keys in your dict with `cars.keys()` then you iterate over each element as `for elem in list:` and print out your information as `print("car: {}, year: {}".format(elem, cars[elem])`

Comment: print("car: {}, year: {}".format(_, cars[_]))
NameError: name '_' is not defined

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
cars = {"Austin 7": 1922, "Lancia Lambda": 1922, "Bugatti Type 35": 1924, "Hanomag 2": 1925, "Ford Model A": 1927, "Cadillac V16": 1930}

list_keys = cars.keys()

for key in list_keys:
   print("car: {}, year: {}".format(key, cars[key]))
```

Comment: `list_keys = cars.keys()` is superfluous. You can iterate directly over the dictionary: `for key in cars:`

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that you can iterate over the keys of a dictionary using the syntax: `for key in dict:`.

```
cars = {"Austin 7": 1922, "Lancia Lambda": 1922, "Bugatti Type 35": 1924, "Hanomag 2": 1925, "Ford Model A": 1927, "Cadillac V16": 1930}

for car in cars:
    print("car: {}, year: {}".format(car, cars[car]))
```

Alternatives exist such as iterating over the items of the dictionary:

```
for car, year in cars.items():
    print(f"car: {car}, year: {year}")
```

`cars.items()` returns a list of tuples containing the key and value. These are unpacked into the variables `car` and `year` which are then printed using an f-string.

Or you can do it in one line using Python f-strings, list comprehension, and tuple unpacking:

```
print(*[f'car: {car}, year: {cars[car]}' for car in cars], sep='\n')
```